# Left join order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have property pictures in table with their sort_order starting from 0 to number of pictures.
What I would like to do is select pictures but I would like it to start from 2.
My approach was:

```
SELECT * FROM property_photos AS pp1 
JOIN property_photos AS pp2 ON pp1.p_id = pp2.p_id 
where pp2.sort_order =2 
and pp2.sort_order <2 
and pp1.sort_order >2 
and pp1.p_id = 3
```

So what I am trying to gain here is the sort order would be like 2,0,1,3,4,5,6,7

so I need a self join but my query doesn't work

Comment: What is "pp2.sort_order=2 **AND** pp2.sort_order<2" supposed to do? these conditions cannot be both true... never ;)

Comment: so my order is like this ; 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... what i am trying to get is 2,0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need a join on this,

```
SELECT *
FROM property_photos
WHERE p_id = 3
ORDER BY (sort_order = 2) DESC, sort_order
```

Comment: I think you need the condition `p_id = 3`.